# match case in scala template doesn't work, in play2

Tags: templates, playframework-2.0

My code in scala template:

```
@session.get("user.id") match {
    case Some(_) => "xx"
    case _ => "yy"
}
<a href="">Logout</a>
```

But the `case ...` be displayed directly to the generated html page:

```
match { case Some(_) => "xx" case _ => "yy" }  Logout
```

And In the generated .template.scala, it's:

```
"""
<body>
"""),_display_(Seq(/*11.4*/session/*11.11*/.get("user.id"))),format.raw/*11.26*/(""" match """),format.raw("""{"""),format.raw/*11.34*/("""
    case Some(_) => "xx"
    case _ => "yy"
"""),format.raw("""}"""),format.raw/*14.4*/("""
<a href="">Logout</a>
"""
```

But I see in the doc, it should support the `match case`: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/ScalaTemplates

```
@connected match {

  case models.Admin(name) => {
    <span class="admin">Connected as admin (@name)</span>
  }

  case models.User(name) => {
    <span>Connected as @name</span>
  }

}
```

**UPDATE1**

Finally, I found a way to work:

```
@defining(session.get("user.id")) { x =>
    @x match {
        case Some(_) => { "xx" }
        case None => {"yy"}
    }
}
```

But it looks so complicated.

**UPDATE2**

Find another simple solution:

```
@{session.get("user.id") match {
    case Some(_) => "xx"
    case _ => "yy"
}}
```

But it doesn't work well in complex case:

```
@{session.get("user.id") match {
    case Some(_) => {<a href="@routes.Users.logout">Logout</a>}
    case _ => "yy"
}}
```

The `@routes.Users.logout` won't be converted.

**UPDATE3**

This is a `getOrElse` solution:

```
@session.get("user.id").map { _ =>
    <a href="@routes.Users.logout">Logout</a>
}.getOrElse {
    Not logged
}
```

It works but it doesn't use `match case`

Comment: What if you enclose the right part of cases into brackets? E.g. `case Some(_) => { "xx" }`

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I was hitting the same problem. Enclosing the right part of the case in curly braces fixed the issue for me.

This works for me:

```
@user match {
    case Some(user) => { Welcome, @user.username! }
    case None => { <a href="@routes.Application.login">Login</a> }
}
```

Without the braces, it gave an error with the space after the { on the match line highlighted. "'case' expected but identifier found."

I also gives me that error if I try to put an @ before the opening curly brace like this:

```
//This gives me the same error
@user match {
    case Some(user) => @{ "Welcome, " + user.username + "!" }
    case None => { <a href="@routes.Application.login">Login</a> }
}
```

Comment: Note: fancy uses of spaces and \n to format code may also trigger the same error I had trouble with something similar to \@users match {
    case Some(users) => {\n @for (\n user <- users \n){ \n \@user.name \n} \n}
    case None => { No users }
}

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to resolve：

```
      <div class="col-md-9">
        @{
          articles collect { 
          case (title,time,shortcontent) => {
            Html(s"""
                <div class="blog-post">
                    <h2 class="blog-post-title"> $title </h2>
                    <p class="blog-post-meta"> $time </p>
                    <p> $shortcontent </p>
                    <hr/>
                </div>
             """)
            }
         }  
        }
    </div>
```

the idea is to return a string and then using a Html method to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

it works fine for me if i wrap the whole match in **@{**

```
@{
    maybeStatus.map { status =>
        status match {
            //render another template or text based on match
            case Ready => ready()
            case NotReady => "hello world"
            case Eligible => eligible()
            case _ => no_match()
        }
    }
}
```